# $a + b + c + d = e + f$ where all variables used are non-zero, positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

I know that it is possible to come up with parameterization for certain relationships between numbers, such as $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$, but is it possible to come up with a parameterization for $a + b + c + d = e + f$ where all of the variables used are positive, non-zero integers? I really have no idea where to begin.

Comment: What do you mean by "parameterization"? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @NoChance, so in the case of Pythagorean Triples $(A, B, C) = (m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2)$ for $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Would there be something similar for this where $(a, b, c, d, e, f) = (...)$?

Comment: I am beginning to see what you mean - However, I don't know an answer.

Comment: You want a bijection, right? What operations/functions do you allow? Just polynomials?

Comment: What about this : $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (x,x+1,x+2,x+3,2x+1,2x+5)$$ ?

Comment: @Arnaud, I am not really sure how to answer your question. In the case of $a + b + c + d = e + f$, all elements used are positive integers, so I am guessing just addition.

Comment: @jmath I mean the formula giving a,b,c,d,e and f in terms of the new parameters m,n,o,p and q (in the case you would have 5 parameters) that you want to be natural integers too.

Comment: @jmath, in other words we do not know what you want. There could be a completely trivial answer to your question if you do not impose anything on the parameters : take a,b,c,d,e as parameters, impose that they are all positive and that e<a+b+c+d and let f=a+b+c+d-e. Surely this is not what you meant?

Comment: @Arnaud, that is correct, those parameters would need to be natural numbers as well.